# Nextjs white screen running project on Replit

Tags: next.js, replit

When I run a Next.js project on Replit, it just shows up as a white screen. This bug affects not just me, but many people.

I'm importing the project from Github, not using the official Nextjs template (which does work fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js has a bit weird system which breaks Replit's port detection, to fix this add this section in your `.replit` config file.

```
[[ports]]
localPort = 3000
externalPort = 80
```